# Accounting format for numbers in a text type input

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, number-formatting

I have built this form in Apps Script for generating cost estimates, it also autofills the values in from a google sheet.
Problem I have and haven't been able to find a solution anywhere is having any numbers in the cost section format in an accounting style ($1,000.00) and still be able to have text in the input. This is because some of our pricing is "TBA" or "Note Only"

[image]

The next issue is the grand total sum, this is the code I am using for the inputs and for the totals

```html
<div class="input-field col s2">
   <input placeholder="Cost" id="devCost9" type="text" class="inputCost" onchange="calculateTotalPrice()">
</div>
```

```
function calculateTotalPrice(){

 var arr = document.querySelectorAll(".inputCost");
 var total = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   if(parseInt(arr[i].value)){
     total += parseInt(arr[i].value);
   }
 }

  document.getElementById("PicExtPrice").value = total;

}
```

Comment: Please only one topic/problem per question, and explain the actual problem so we can understand/reproduce it. _"is having any numbers in the cost section format in an accounting style ($1,000.00) and still be able to have text in the input"_ and _"The next issue is the grand total sum"_ are both no specific problems -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please don't include any information about yourself in the posts, you could add that in your profile. Many questions about using JavaScript in the cliente side of  Google Apps Script web applications have already have an answer, please search before posting a question and if you didn't find the answer add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement two helper functions to display the value as currency.  Below I have `toCurrency()`, and then to add values I have another `fromCurrency()` to remove $ sign etc.

I have a simple HTML dialog.

[image]

The HTML file looks like this - HTML_Test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('CSS_Test'); ?>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
          Line 1
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          <input class="inputCost" id="cost1" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
          Line 2
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          <input class="inputCost" id="cost2" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
          Line 3
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          <input class="inputCost" id="cost3" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
          Line 4
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          <input class="inputCost" id="cost4" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
          <input type="button" onclick="buttonOnClick()" value="Total">
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          <input class="totalCost" id="totalCost" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?!= include('JS_Test'); ?>    
  </body>
</html>
```

I use CSS display to display a table - CSS_Test.html

```
<style>
  .table {
    display: table;
  }
  .row {
    display: table-row;
  }
  .cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

And the javascript file to introduce the helper functions and the summation - JS_Test.html.  When I press the Total button the summation is displayed.

```
<script>
  function toCurrency(value) {
    try {
      if( isNaN(Number(value)) ) return value;
      return Number(value).toLocaleString("en-US",{style:"currency", currency:"USD"});    
    }
    catch(err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  function fromCurrency(value) {
    try {
      let num = Number(value.replace(/[\$,]/g,''));
      return isNaN(num) ? 0 : num;
    }
    catch(err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  function buttonOnClick() {
    try {
      let costs = document.querySelectorAll(".inputCost");
      let total = 0;
      costs.forEach( cost => {
          total = total+fromCurrency(cost.value);
        }
      );
      document.getElementById("totalCost").value = toCurrency(total);
    }
    catch(err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  (function () {
    try {
      let values = ["2200","TBA","Note Only","-15"];
      document.getElementById("cost1").value = toCurrency(values[0]);
      document.getElementById("cost2").value = toCurrency(values[1]);
      document.getElementById("cost3").value = toCurrency(values[2]);
      document.getElementById("cost4").value = toCurrency(values[3]);
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }
  )();
</script>
```